# Meaning of "Open chest surgery is not needed when putting on a coat"

Tags: meaning, english-to-german

In OOP-Design exist the SOLID-principles. Many Articles about [Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) (O in SOLID) cites the phrase in title. But it doesn't make much sense to us in the office. So maybe someone can explain this phrase to me.

Comment: An attempt of translation, at least?

Comment: the tranbslation into german word by word doesn't make sense.

But if you like:

Eine operation am offenen Brustkorb ist nicht notwendig wenn man einen Mantel anzieht.

if have thought that coat maybe means the chest with flesh and bones, but it doesn't helped me much. I only found this phrase in this SOLID articles.

Comment: _Man braucht keine Operation am offenen Herzen, um einen Mantel anzuziehen._ Does make sense in this context (extending a class without changing its inner workings). However, I don't see how this is on-topic for German.SE. Migrate to Programmers.SE?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an English expression used to illustrate a software engineering concept, and has nothing to do with the German language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't sure where tu put this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wenn man Software entwickelt, will man die Interfaces der verschiedenen Komponenten untereinander stabil halten, d. h., sie sollen sich möglichst nicht verändern. Trotzdem soll aber alles damit möglich sein, was infrage kommt, d. h., sie sollen sich bei Bedarf erweitern lassen ("Abwärtskompatibilität").

Beispiel HTTP: Dort kann im Header neben den Pflichtfeldern alles Mögliche stehen, sogar [ASCII Art](http://www.nextthing.org/archives/2005/08/07/fun-with-http-headers) (Erweiterbarkeit); wenn eine Zeile nicht verstanden wird, wird sie einfach ignoriert. Dadurch ist sichergestellt, dass alle Teilnehmer zumindest einen gewissen identischen Grundwortschatz haben, d. h., bei der grundlegenden Funktionalität (Webseiten übertragen) versteht jeder Browser und jeder Server, was der jeweils andere will.

Wenn jemand einen Mantel anzieht ("putting on a coat"), ist also keine Operation am offenen Brustkorb ("open chest surgery") notwendig. Erweiterungen, der Mantel also, müssen einfach möglich sein und keine großen Eingriffe erfordern, die womöglich andere Dinge kaputt machen ("never touch a running system").

Comment: Danke deine Antwort und der Kommentar von chirlu, haben mit es klar gemacht.

Comment: Hab das Kommentar irgendwie überlesen, habe nur gesehen dass da noch eine Frage ohne Antwort ist und gedacht ich schreib mal was;)